# Angular in a NodeJs Server

Tags: node.js, angular, server

I'm beginner in Angular. I have a nodejs server and I have Angular for the front end. Now I would like to know if it's possible to have just one server for both ? 
Because in some videos from youtube, they had one server for node and one server for angular.

Thank you, bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a basic level you'd need to set the static path for your built, static Angular files and if you are using Angular routing you'd probably want to direct all requests to your `index.html` of the Angular project so that Angular can handle all client side routing.

For example, setting the static path for a built Angular CLI project that sits in the default `public` folder created by express-generator. The example uses `dist` as that is the default destination of the Angular CLI project when you execute `ng build`.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist')));
```

Catch-all route to direct any requests not caught by your Express application route definitions, such as RESTful routes returning JSON data or similar, to the Angular project's `index.html`:

```
// some routes
var users = require('./routes/users');
app.use('/users', users);

// other routes
var todos = require('./routes/todos');
app.use('/todos', todos);

// catch-all route
// needs to go AFTER all other express server route definitions
app.use('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'dist', 'index.html')));
```

If using Angular CLI, during development you can run the projects separately, using a [proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy).

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to have one server for both.

You can serve your AngularJS files via your favourite HTTP server (e.g. `express`) on your NodeJS server as static files like so:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))
```

Where `client` is the directory containing your front-end content.